# Smart Card External Authenticate 6982 error

Tags: php, smartcard, apdu

I'm trying to make security communicate with S.A.M.(Secure Access Module)
Firstly I send this MSE:SET APDU for External Authenticate:

```
//83 is my private key's ID. F8 is algorithm identifier 
OutgoingAPDU : 002281A4068001F8840183
ResponseSW1SW2 : 9000
```

Before send external auth. documents says encrypt with RSAES-OAEP PKCS #1 so I'm using this openssl command for encryption.

```
openssl_public_encrypt($dataForEncryption, $output, $publicKey['key'], OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
//$firstPartOfData => first 488 of $output
//$secondPartOfData => last 24 of $output
//total $output is 512
```

First of all is that true padding for RSAES-OAEP PKCS #1.

And then external auth. APDU commands.

```
//strlen($firstPartOfData) = 488
OutgoingAPDU : 10820000F4.$firstPartOfData
ResponseSW1SW2 : 9000
//strlen($firstPartOfData) = 24
OutgoingAPDU : 008200000C.$secondPartOfData
ResponseSW1SW2 : 6982
```

Where am I missing ? Or where is the mistake. I could'n find out the problem.

Comment: Can we rest assured that `$output` contains just hexadecimal bytes? Do you have information about the hash function that is part of OAEP padding?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes '$output' contains binary data. I convert it hex before separate parts. I'dont have any idea about openssl OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING but my project document wants me RSAES-OAEP PKCS #1 (sha256). Are they same ?

Comment: The default is SHA-1 so that might explain the difference. The hash is a configuration parameter of MGF1, which is the only possible configuration parameter of OAEP.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I could'n find the MGF1 configurations on openssl(php) so how can i do this(RSAES-OAEP PKCS #1) encryption with openssl or can i do it with openssl ?

Comment: See the top comment [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php). Let me know if you succeed, and I'll convert my comments into an answer. Note that SHA-1 is still considered secure for use within MGF1. You're unlikely to find MGF1 in *public functions* as it generally seen as an implementation detail of RSA OAEP and PSS....

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm trying to add phpseclib on my project as library but i couldn't do it for now. I'm new at phpstorm and php .

Comment: Can't help you there, but take your time, **I** am not in a hurry :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes '$phpsec->setMGFHash('sha256');' '$phpsec->setHash('sha256');' '$phpsec->loadKey($cer["key"]);' '$phpsec->encrypt($plaintext)' is worked. I get 9000

Comment: Created an answer from the comments.

Comment: Could you test if your code still works **without** `setHash`, so just `setMGFHash` to set the hash?

Comment: I tested it but couldn't works without setHash (6982 )

Comment: Hmm, OK, weird; *normally* OAEP just uses the hash for MGF1, so having to set it twice shouldn't be needed. Thanks for testing this out otherwise I would have had to install the package (and my Linux VM is seriously out of date).

Comment: OK. No problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA / OAEP requires the configuration of a type of Mask Generation Function to create the OAEP padding. This Mask Generation Function type has only one real member: MGF1, so in general this configuration is implicit (i.e. you don't have to configure it yourself). MGF1 itself however allows the user to configure the hash used internally. MGF1 uses SHA-1 by default (in a secure fashion) but it can be configured with SHA-256 or any other hash as well.

In your case OAEP with SHA-256 was used within the smart card, which will result in an error during decryption (the unpadding of the message after modular exponentiation with the private exponent) if you used the SHA-1 default in PHP.

To set the hash correctly you can use phpseclib with the following code:

```
 $phpsec->setMGFHash('sha256');
 $phpsec->setHash('sha256');
 $phpsec->loadKey($cer["key"]);
 $phpsec->encrypt($plaintext);
```

---

The error generated status word `6982` on the smart card. This is a rather badly chosen status word as it means "security conditions not satisfied", which you would *expect* if the access conditions for the decryption operation are not satisfied. However, ISO/IEC 7816-4 doesn't really specify when the status words should be generated (which is just stupid, but that's how it is).